# Update Azure data base using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I would like to know if it's possible to update an Azure database, using C#. I can send the updates to Azure using a bacpac file in C#, but I only want to update it if I add a new table or something like that, thank you.

Comment: Would you like to be able to update the database with new tables runtime from c# or could you describe in more detail what you would like to do?

Comment: Yes, my problem is the file.bacpac, because it has all database tables and data,but it takes a lot of time, so I want update only database if I make changes .

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/), if you can do it on SQL Server 2014 then you should be able to do something like this on SQL Azure v12.